# Terraform iterate over map and create nested resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, infrastructure-as-code

I'm trying to iterate over a map and create some additional settings in the `aws_codebuild_project`. This is my first time working with loops in Terraform. My main source of confusion is that I do not know if a resource has to "support" loops, or if it is possible to iterate almost everywhere inside a resource?

```
variable "custom_environment_variables" {
  type    = map(any)
  default = {}
}

resource "aws_codebuild_project" "my_project" {
  # other props...

  environment {
    type = "LINUX_CONTAINER"
    # more props

    # some hardcoded environment_variable
    environment_variable {
      name  = "APP_STAGE"
      value = var.app_stage
    }
    # some dynamic environment_variable
    dynamic "custom_environment_variable" {
      for_each = var.custom_environment_variables
      environment_variable {
        name  = custom_environment_variable.key
        value = custom_environment_variable.value
      }
    }
  }
}
```

this code causes this error:

```
│ Error: Unsupported block type
│ 
│   on ../modules/static_web_pipeline/main.tf line 155, in resource "aws_codebuild_project" "my_project":
│  155:     dynamic "custom_environment_variable" {
│ 
│ Blocks of type "custom_environment_variable" are not expected here.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The name of the dynamic block has to match the name of the block to be created and within the block the name has to be `content`:

```
dynamic "environment_variable" {
  for_each = var.custom_environment_variables
  content {
    name  = environment_variable.key
    value = environment_variable.value
  }
}
```

To answer *"My main source of confusion is that I do not know if a resource has to "support" loops, or if it is possible to iterate almost everywhere inside a resource?"*:

No, a resource does not need to "support" loops, but you can still not iterate everything and everywhere. You can only iterate blocks and since the resource supports the block `environment_variable` you can can use a *dynamic* block to create multiple `environment_variable` blocks. Think of the iteration as a core terraform feature, the resource itself does not ever see the iteration or know about it, the resource only sees multiple  `environment_variable` blocks as if you would have typed them manually.